# React API request is being made before props are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, react-hooks

In my React project I'm trying to fetch some data from a database when a Link is pressed. When I do this, I can see that my props are undefined which causes a blank React page to be rendered.

I verified that `id` was not undefined as a prop by logging it when the Link is pressed. However, when I log it in the `useEffect()` hook it's undefined. How can I only make the request once the props have been passed?

```
const user = useContext(UserContext);

const id = props.followerId;

useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3000/users/followers/${id})
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    user.setFollower(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `id` in dependency array so that if the `id` changes then the `useEffect` will run

and add a guard clause in `useEffect` so that request will only go if there is an `id` as:

```
const id = props.followerId;

useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {   // IF GUARD CLAUSE ONLY RUN IF ID IS SOMETHING
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3000/users/followers/${id}`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    user.setFollower(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}, [id]);   // ADD ID IN DEPENDENCY ARRAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` as dependency in useEffect. Moreover, add a boolean check on id too.

```
const user = useContext(UserContext);

const id = props.followerId;

useEffect(() => {
!!id & & axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3000/users/followers/${id})
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    user.setFollower(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}, [id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

useEffect with empty array means it only execute when component mount. if you use id in useEffetc dependency array then it will execute whenever id change its value and on mount also. so if id exist then call `getFollower`. like this

```
const user = useContext(UserContext);

const id = props.followerId;

useEffect(() => {
   const getFollower=(uid)=>{  
       axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/followers/${uid}`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    user.setFollower(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
       }
   }

if(id) getFollower(id)
}, [id]);
```